# Why does git think my file has been or should be deleted?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I'm working as part of a team using Visual Studio, using git provided by Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online). We're using feature branches, and merging into a central branch as we complete our work.

My current work has been committed on the feature branch in an incomplete state, and one of my colleagues who is doing a separate part of the work (my work is C#/.net, theirs is web/UI) has done a temporary (uncommitted) merge in visual studio in order to check that our work will integrate correctly.

Their work has been committed to our central branch, without this merge apparently being completed, and as I am pulling updates from our central branch into my feature branch, a number of the files I have created on this feature branch appear to be deleted, without raising a merge conflict.

Why has this happened? 
What can we do to prevent this?
How can I avoid picking through every file that I or another member of my team has changed in order to merge my changes without unexpected deletions/reverts?

Comment: are you using the git bash or a gui?

Comment: @Eashi I am using both, according to expediency. The rest of my team are using only Visual Studio as the GUI.

Comment: In that case you are probably aware of the quality of visual studios git client. I would not be surprised if it ate your stuff, e.g. automatically stashed it to avoid a merge conflict.

Comment: Yes, I am aware it has its limitations, although I suspect that what I'm running into is a _"feature"_ of git - it may well be that any selective merge in git will cause this sort of problem and/or confusion. Unfortunately, the obvious solution seems to be a selective merge.

Comment: How do you pull update from central? Using git pull command?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT there is a central branch, let's call it origin/master. I pull from it by doing a fetch and then a merge, if I am in git, or a pull on the master branch in visual studio, then a merge across from the (now local) master branch.

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature of git - when a source branch is merged into a destination branch, that merge will normally have a record of all changes made on the source branch, and my team-mate checked in a merge (unintentionally!) which did not record my changes, and git therefore saw those files as deleted, and my changes as being undone.

There's probably room for Visual Studio, as a git client, to improve clarity around whether a state you are committing is currently being interpreted as a merge and whether you can cancel the merge. There's also room for improvement on the branches view, which would have allowed me to find this erroneous merge more rapidly.